# How to get a stack trace in .NET in normal execution?

Tags: .net, vb.net, logging, stack-trace

In VB .NET, I know I can get a stack trace by looking at the value of `ex.StackTrace` when handling an exception.  How can I get the functions on the stack when I am not handling an exception?  I am looking to implement a logging system of some sort to record the steps the user takes prior to a crash to assist in debugging.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`Environment.StackTrace` gives you a string, but for more detailed information and options, use the `StackTrace` class.

To be more specific, check out the constructor options:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.stacktrace.aspx

If you need the stack trace starting at the caller's frame (e.g. in a logging function: you don't want everything to start with `MyLogMethod`), you should try this one, which takes an `int` parameter, the number of frames to skip.

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wybch8k4.aspx

If you need the stack trace without source information (e.g. if you don't want to give away information about your source code), try this one:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6zh7csxz.aspx

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 9):

[Environment.StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.stacktrace.aspx)

Answer (score 7):

```
System.Environment.StackTrace
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use these calls to get more detailed information such as  `GetILOffset`, `GetNativeOffset` or `GetType`:

```
Import System.Diagnostics
            
Debug.WriteLine("Call Stack:")
Dim stackTrace As StackTrace = New StackTrace()         
Dim stackFrames() As StackFrame = stackTrace.GetFrames() 

For Each stackFrame As StackFrame In stackFrames
    Debug.WriteLine(stackFrame.GetMethod().Name)
Next
```

See https://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-callstack/